# "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found" How do I resolve this error in chrome dev tools?

Tags: html

I am working on a project with just the basics, an index.html file, and a script.js file.  Every time I view the index.html file, in my dev tools I get the "GET /favicon.ico" Error (404): "Not found" error. I saw several other posts on this and I have tried all of those "fixes".
Below is my html file and an image of my file tree.

```
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">

<meta name="author" content="Thomas E. Kremer">
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/seethrough_1.png" style="height: 100px; width: 100px;">    
<title>Info HTML</title>
```

[image: his is my file tree:]

Comment: I know it's hard to list all the things you've already tried, but without any information on them at all, it's down to luck whether someone suggests something you've already tried or not. Can you [edit] to mention some of the ideas that seemed most promising, and exactly what happened when you tried them?

Comment: As an aside, because it's unlikely to affect your problem, [the `link` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) does not have a `style` attribute - it's not something that's going to be displayed in the page, so styling it wouldn't make any sense.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  I was curious abut that too.  I know it goes on the tab but I didn't know if size mattered.

Comment: @ThomasKrenner Where and how the site icon is displayed varies by browser, and if the site *could* conrtol the size a lot of things would break - the icons on my Firefox window are currently 18px high, so if you succeeded in forcing one to 100px it would look terrible.

Comment: @IMSoP That makes sense.  I am still learning the basics on and off.  Thank you for the information, it is greatly appreciated.  When I first put that link in my code, the icon was at the top of the tab, then I do a hard refresh and I get the error and the icon is gone.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I created a new project, I used a template that I created earlier when the icon was displaying and now it works fine.  I replaced the original link with the following link.

```
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/images/seethrough_1.png">
```

I appreciate IMSoP for correcting my errors of trying to style this icon up to 100px, while that wasn't the actual problem, I forgot that link tags don't need to use styling.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that the page cannot load the 'favorite icon file,' favicon.ico, in the root directory of the webpage due to the icon or image file not being found (error code 404 - Not Found). To fix this, copy your favicon.ico to the root folder if the file is missing, and check the link to the icon or image on the webpage.

If you are using an .ico file, use the following HTML code:

```
<link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

If you are using an image file (.png) instead, ensure that the 'type' attribute is set according to the image type and use the appropriate 'href' attribute. For example:

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="favicon.png">
```